# Dragging arrow around using touch point Bubble Shooter libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

So, now I've got into my second problem of implementing the arrow. The rotation works fine from this **[link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/161777/implement-bubble-shooter-arrow-rotation-using-libgdx)** **but I have to calculate the angle from a touch point to the middle of the arrow placement.**

I've already calculated that angle, well if I'm not mistaken. I used a vertical distance that is just the touch points y coordinate since the center y coordinate is 0. For the x coordinate I subtracted the touch point minus the texture regions x coordinate in draw function.

**Then to calculate the angle I used arcus tangent inside divided the vertical length by the horizontal length, then multiplied by 180 / PI to get the angle in degrees.**

The thing is that this worked a bit like I wanted, but not exactly. Because when taking the touch points coordinates and bottom center coordinates the invisible triangle that is created will be created as a mirrored triangle on the half side of the screen. Meaning when going over to the other side with a finger the angle was negative. Tried using a the math absolute function but then the arrow bounced back when it reached the angle limit.

Draw function:

```
    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(EtherSky.camera.combined);
        spriteBatch.begin();
        spriteBatch.draw(textureRegion,
            x - textureRegion.getRegionWidth() / 2, y,
            textureRegion.getRegionWidth() / 2, 0, 
            textureRegion.getRegionWidth(), 
            textureRegion.getRegionHeight(), 
            1.0f, 1.0f, degrees);
        spriteBatch.end();
     }
```

Input function:

```
    @Override
    public void input() {

    /*
    if (Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() > 3 && degrees < 90) {
        degrees++;
    }
    else if (Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() < -3 && degrees > -90) {
        degrees--;
    }*/

    // Distance from arrow bottom center point to touch point
    float distance = (float)Math.sqrt(
                      Math.pow((inputManager.touchPoint.x - (x - textureRegion.getRegionWidth() / 2)), 2) +
                      Math.pow((inputManager.touchPoint.y - 0), 2));

    float verticalDistance = inputManager.touchPoint.y;
    float horizontalDistance = inputManager.touchPoint.x - (x - textureRegion.getRegionWidth() / 2);
    float angle = (float)Math.abs(Math.atan(verticalDistance / horizontalDistance) * 180 / Math.PI);

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        degrees = angle;
    }
    System.out.println("Player (" + Gdx.input.getX() + ", " + Gdx.input.getY() + ")");
    System.out.println("Degrees: " + degrees + " Angle: " + angle);
    }
```

The black dots on the image represents touch points and this is what the invisible triangles would look like if I'm not imagining wrongly. 
Example image:
[image]

**UPDATED CODE**

```
    float verticalDistance = inputManager.touchPoint.y;
    float horizontalDistance = inputManager.touchPoint.x - x; // (x - textureRegion.getRegionWidth() / 2)
    float angle = (float)Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(verticalDistance, horizontalDistance)) - 90;

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            degrees = angle;

            if (degrees < 90)
                degrees = 89;
    }
```

I tried to do this but it doesn't work because then I get the arrow stuck at 89 degrees forever. Notice that this is not the arrow pointing straight up, it's the arrow pointing to the left.

I am aware why the code doesn't work but I don't know how to get it to work.

**UPDATED CODE FOR FUTURE READERS (ANSWER)**

```
private void inputFollowFinger() {
        float verticalDistance = inputManager.touchPoint.y;
        float horizontalDistance = inputManager.touchPoint.x - x;
        float angle = (float)Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(verticalDistance, horizontalDistance)) - 90;

        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            degrees = angle;
            arrowStayAt90Degrees();
        }
    }

private void arrowStayAt90Degrees() {
    final int stayAtDeg = 90;
    final int adjustDeg = 180;
    if (degrees < -adjustDeg) {
        degrees = stayAtDeg;
    }
    else if (degrees < -stayAtDeg) {
        degrees = -stayAtDeg;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already realized that but the arrow either: 

1. Moves like a limit was not set or
2. Sets the limit forever and I can't move the arrow anymore

I don't see what I'm missing

Comment: Sorry for the late response. As the bottom half of the circle in my answer only contain negative values, and also taking into consideration the `-90`, the test should be: `if(degrees < -180) { degrees = 90; } else if(degrees < -90) { degrees = -90; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem once. Here is how I approach it.

[image: figure]

The left side shows how angles are represented in Java (or at least how I see them represented). The `Math.*` functions work like that and give results like that.

With that being said we just calculate the angle this way:

```
angle = atan2(dy, dx)
```

Where `dy` is the vertical distance and `dx` is the horizontal one. Using `atan2` is better, so that you won't get an error when `dx` is 0.

Now, we have to take into account that the arrow in its neutral state is already rotated by 90° as shown on the right side from the image above. So the actual angle should be (substracting 90°):

```
angle = atan2(dy, dx) - 90
```

**Java code:**

```
public void input() {
    float dy = inputManager.touchPoint.y;
    float dx = inputManager.touchPoint.x - x;

    float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(dy, dx)) - 90;

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        degrees = angle;
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- The horizontal distance `dx` should be `inputManager.touchPoint.x - x`. We dont care about the origin here, it is only needed in the rendering process.
- It's better to cache the values `textureRegion.getRegionWidth()` and `textureRegion.getRegionHeight()` as properties `width` and `height`, respectively. That will make the code much concise (thus readable) and reduce the overhead caused by `.`.

Comment: Thanks again, but how did you solve so that the arrow stays laying down at 90 degrees (180 degrees in your image). Sure, it's not that big of a deal since the user can't put a finger beneath the screen, but my arrow doesn't stop at 90. It points downwards a little bit. 

I have done an if statement checking the angle from 90 to -90, but when I reach that limit the arrow doesn't come back up again, of course. So that's the part I wonder about.

Comment: @kevvex I'm not sure I understand your comment. Can you explain it more?

Comment: I wrote an if statement so that the arrow would stop at 90 degrees pointing straight to the right and -90 pointing straight to the left, but to do so I have to set an interval from 90 to -90 and then I set the degrees/angle to 90. And that is why the arrow gets stuck there. I post the code in updated version. 

For some reason the arrow points downwards a little.

Comment: @kevvex Can you post that code (add it to the question)?

Comment: It have already been posted.